# All paused partitions assigned to a consumer are revoked when another consumer joins the same group

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a consumer subscribed to a topic and it is polling 3 partitions. Because of my specific use case, this consumer invokes *pause(TopicPartition)* method, so  all partitions are going to be set in paused. Anyway, it continues polling in order to send the heartbeat. Then, a second consumer joins the same group. Coordinator rebalances partitions. It is expected that the 3 partitions being balanced between both consumers, however all partitions (3) are revoked from the first consumer and they are assigned to the second one.

I could verify that in my first consumer at rebalance time (with all partitions in pause). The Coordinator invokes ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsRevoked but it never invokes ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned

Why Coordinator revoke all partitions from the first consumer? Is it related to paused partitions? Has anyone experienced the same behavior when rebalancing paused partitions?